MM quotes replacement time in HFT
Market Makers quote on the minimum quote requirements of the market set by regulators, and they are also free to quote as they wish. In High Frequency Trading, when quotes are hit, MM will replace them.

My question is how fast does this happen?
Is there a cooling period, and if yes what is usually the time?
What if
3a. Only the min quote requirements are hit?
3b. Big amount of quotes are hit?


In High Frequency Trading, Market Makers have the ability to replace quotes almost instantaneously when they are hit. There is typically no cooling period required, as the technology used in HFT allows for rapid adjustments to be made in response to market conditions.
If only the minimum quote requirements are hit, Market Makers will adjust their quotes accordingly. However, if a large amount of quotes are hit simultaneously, Market Makers may need to reassess their strategies and potentially widen their spreads or adjust their pricing dynamically in order to manage their risk exposure. Ultimately, the speed at which Market Makers respond to hits on their quotes will depend on the specific trading platform and technology they are using.

Thanks for the response. It is clear to me that Market Maker like to adjust their quotes as fast as possible. Could they detect if a liquidation of a portfolio is happening by looking at their quote matches? And so try to take advantage of it if possible by not replacing Minimum Quote Requirements (thus getting matches deeper in their book)?

Yes, Market Makers may be able to detect a portfolio liquidation event by closely monitoring their quote matches and overall trading activity. In such situations, Market Makers may adjust their strategies in order to take advantage of the market conditions. This may involve not replacing minimum quote requirements or adjusting their pricing dynamically to capitalize on the increased trading volume and volatility. However, it is important to note that Market Makers are also subject to regulatory requirements, so they must act within the boundaries of transparent trading practices.

In the realm of High-Frequency Trading (HFT), the efficiency of trading infrastructure plays a crucial role, particularly in determining the round-trip time (RTT) for quotes. RTT can be measured in nanoseconds, underscoring the critical importance of technological capability in HFT environments.
Firstly, about your first question:
A few critics about High-Frequency Trading and Market Maker Response Times
Round-Trip Time Analysis: In an HFT scenario, suppose the time taken for sending quotes based on current market conditions is approximately 750 nanoseconds. Upon receiving a hit on these quotes, the market maker must acknowledge this hit and respond, doubling the time to around 1.5 milliseconds for a complete round trip. This duration illustrates how swiftly market makers must operate, adjusting their quotes to reflect real-time market dynamics. The actual figures may vary based on the sophistication and speed of the underlying infrastructure. In laboratory settings, these times might be even shorter due to the optimized conditions.
System Layers and Computational Overhead: When a quote is hit, the response isn't instantaneous due to the computational processes involved in the software layer. These processes add a time load that must be factored into the overall turnaround. Market makers need to evaluate the complexity of their algorithms, the prevailing market conditions, and their technological framework to enhance efficiency and reduce latency.
Regulatory and Operational Considerations
Secondly, depends on the market you are playing, cooling periods may vary depending on the regulations of market:
Typically, there is no mandated cooling period in HFT between when a quote is hit and when a new one can be posted. The primary limitation is the physical and computational capability of the market makers’ systems. Nonetheless, specific trading venues might impose rules to prevent order book manipulation, which can indirectly influence the speed at which quotes are refreshed.
In terms of your third question about Impact of the Type of Quote Hit
Minimum Quote Requirements: When hits occur strictly at the minimum quote levels, market makers generally replenish these quickly to meet regulatory requirements and maintain market presence. Such minimum requirements are designed to ensure continuous liquidity and trading opportunities, facilitating a stable trading environment.
Large Volumes of Quotes: When a large volume of quotes is hit, the necessary response becomes more intricate. Such substantial transactions may indicate significant market events or trends, prompting market makers to adapt not just the speed, but also the pricing and volume of their new quotes. Adjustments may include widening the bid-ask spread or modifying inventory strategies to manage perceived risks and market volatility effectively.
Strategic Enhancements for Market Makers
To optimize operations in such a fast-paced environment, market makers can employ several strategies:
Technology Upgrades: Investing in state-of-the-art trading and data processing technologies in terms of HW, and SW to minimize latency.
Algorithm Optimization: Refining algorithms to ensure they can quickly adapt to market conditions without requiring excessive computational resources.
Risk Management Enhancements: Developing sophisticated models and algorithms to better predict market volatility and adjust quotes accordingly.
Regulatory Compliance: Staying updated with all regulatory requirements and adjusting operations to maintain compliance without compromising on speed.
These strategic considerations are vital for market makers aiming to thrive in the competitive landscape of high-frequency trading, ensuring they can respond to market dynamics efficiently and maintain robust trading operations.

Thanks for the detailed response, I understand what you mean. I see that market makers are keen on keeping the Minimum Quote Requirements if hit and not change their spread. However, I have one more specific question on that. If the Minimum Quote Requirements are hit multiple times in short time (say 5 times in a second) would they change the spread or wait until replacing them? Is is suspicious that  Minimum Quote Requirements are hit multiple times in this short time ?

it depends on the strategy and market conditions/ If the market is volatile and they are able to hit 5 times in a second, they may choose the increase the spread between bid and ask. By this change, they may not sit on the top of the book but as a tradeoff they will get more spread. It is a trader off and they have to think about requirement that the market request. If they dont provide that one, they wont get the rebate and even in the worst case scenario, they might lose their MM status.

Aiui about Minimum Quota Requirements hit, you mean that they are getting warned by not providing and reach that requirements. In that case as I mentioned before, I think they would not get rebate . There are supervisory authorities responsible for overseeing market makers and ensuring they adhere to minimum quota requirements among other regulatory obligations. So hitting them multiple times might be suspicious.
(I have got a -1, did I said or explain sth wrong in my answer :/)

Keep in mind that the Minimum Quote Requirements for a rebate (or regulatory) also have a period of time. For example, 85% of the time. So they can 'afford' not quoting for some time.
(I didn't put the -1, I still cannot vote :|)
